# Delete SQLite row with RecyclerView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to delete a row of data in SQLite with `RecyclerView`? Before when I used a `ListView` I just set and `onClickListener` and did :

`public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

Then passed the `id` onto my database like so: `databaseAdapter.deleteScore(id)`

but now since it is all handled in the `RecyclerViewAdapter` class can you still get the row id and delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. What I did was in the `RecyclerView's` `onLongClick(final View view)` I created an instance of my sql database and called my deleteScore method as so: `sqLiteDBadapter.deleteScore(temp2);` <- temp2 is the rowid of the list item in the sql database.

And here is my `getRowid` and my `deleteScore` methods in my `SQLiteDBadapter` class:

getRowid:

```
public String getRowid(String date) {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE date = ?" , new String[] { date });
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        long temp;
        temp = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
        rowID = String.valueOf(temp);
        Log.i("----_ROW ID = ", rowID);
    }else  if (!c.moveToFirst())
        Log.i("CURSOR ERROR", " CURSOR INDEX MOST LIKELY 0");
    else
        c.moveToFirst();

    return rowID;
}
```

deleteScore:

```
public boolean deleteScore(long rowId) {
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,KEY_ROWID + "= ?", new String[] { rowID}) > 0;
}
```